# Issues with getting .NET 4.7.2 for Visual studio 15.9.11 (professional)

Tags: .net-framework, visual-studio-2010, azure-activedirectory, ssrs

**Aim**; connect SSRS files to a azure DB with MFA. According to this doc https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/azure-active-directory?view=azuresqldb-current, I should be able to do this with the latest version of both Visual Studio and .Net framework.

**Where I am stuck**; I have got the latest version of VS, however a Report Server project does not have Active Directory Interactive Authentication. I guess this is due to .NET.

**What I have tried**: I ran the install for .NET 4.7.2 runtime & Dev Pack. The runtime installer said it was already installed. This did not change anything.

However according to VS and the registry I have .NET version 7.7.03####. See images attached.

[image]

[image]

Would very much appreciate any thoughts on this issue?

Edit: However, if I try to create a C# project in VS, 4.7.2 is available.

Comment: Your screenshot indicates the version that is installed is 4.7.2 installed (4.7.03062) is 4.7.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would very much appreciate any thoughts on this issue?

Your screenshot indicates the .NET Framework version you have installed is actually is 4.7.2 (4.7.03062).

> if I try to create a C# project in VS, 4.7.2 is available.

This provides undeniable evidence that 4.7.2 (or it's targeting pack) is actually installed.

Comment: I know that 4.7.03062 is .NET Framework 4.7.2 since I am using 1903 and the only version of .NET Framework that can be installed on that version is 4.7.2 and I have the same value on my system.

Comment: Thank you for responding, I got a friend to run and compile a consoleApp in VS using NET 4.7.2 and that worked fine. This suggests it may not be a .NET issue and some other reason that AD interactive is not available.